# read_html resulting in first row as column header name despite header = None

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
url = "http://www.espn.com/nba/standings"
dfs = pd.read_html(url, header = None)

dfs[1]
```

resulting in:

```
1* --MILMilwaukee Bucks
0   2y --TORToronto Raptors
1   3x --PHIPhiladelphia 76ers
2   4x --BOSBoston Celtics
3   5x --INDIndiana Pacers
0   2y --TORToronto Raptors
```

`1* --MILMilwaukee Bucks` shouldn't be a column name

I feel like I am doing something wrong (haven't used Pandas in a while), but from what I have read `header = None` should work.

Comment: what is your pandas version ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen  '0.24.2'

Comment: @Moondra Have you checked my answer. It answers your question. Have a look at it :)

Comment: @0xPrateek  Sorry, I haven't checked yet, but I will do so when I just finish up some work.

Comment: @Moondra Sounds Good ..!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried doing it but in my case also `header = None` didn't work(I am searching for the reason why it didn't work) well instead of it you can use `header = 0` it works well.

```
data = pd.read_html("test.html",header = 0)
print(data)
```

** Output::**

```
[  Programming Language             Creator  Year
0                    C      Dennis Ritchie  1972
1               Python    Guido Van Rossum  1989
2                 Ruby  Yukihiro Matsumoto  1995]
```

This will work for you. ;)

Comment: Sorry, just got around to it, but it doesn't work with my example:

`      1* --MILMilwaukee Bucks`
0     2y --TORToronto Raptors
1  3x --PHIPhiladelphia 76ers
2      4x --BOSBoston Celtics
3      5x --INDIndiana Pacers
4       6x --BKNBrooklyn Nets